# How to represent a dependency graph with alternative paths

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dependencies

I'm having some trouble trying to represent and  manipulate dependency graphs in this scenario:

- a node has some dependencies that have to be solved
- every path must not have dependencies loops (like in DAG graphs)
- every dependency could be solved by more than one other node

I starts from the target node and recursively look for its dependencies, but have to mantain the above properties, in particular the third one.

Just a little example here:

I would like to have a graph like the following one

```
           (A)
          /   \
         /     \
        /       \
  [(B),(C),(D)] (E)
   /\        \
  /  \       (H)
(F)  (G)
```

which means:

- F,G,C,H,E have no dependencies
- D dependends on H
- B depends on F and G
- A depends on E *and*

  - B *or*
  - C *or*
  - D

So, if I write down all the possible topological-sorted paths to A I should have:

1. E -> F -> G -> B -> A
2. E -> C -> A
3. E -> H -> D -> A

How can I model a graph with these properties? Which kind of data structure is the more suitable to do that?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the graph.

Comment: Also, are not F, E, H, D, A and others also valid topsorts?

Comment: yep, there are also other valid topsorts. I wrote just a few examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a normal adjacency list, with an additional property, wherein a node knows its the other nodes that would also satisfy the same dependency. This means that B,C,D should all know that they belong to the same equivalence class. You can achieve this by inserting them all into a set.

```
Node:
    List<Node> adjacencyList
    Set<Node> equivalentDependencies
```

To use this data-structure in a topo-sort, whenever you remove a source, and remove all its outgoing edges, also remove the nodes in its equivalency class, their outgoing edges, and recursively remove the nodes that point to them.
From wikipedia:

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edges
while S is non-empty do
    remove a node n from S
    add n to tail of L
    for each node o in the equivalency class of n <===removing equivalent dependencies
        remove j from S
            for each node k with an edge e from j to k do
                remove edge e from the graph
                if k has no other incoming edges then
                    insert k into S    
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
        remove edge e from the graph
        if m has no other incoming edges then
            insert m into S
if graph has edges then
    return error (graph has at least one cycle)
else 
    return L (a topologically sorted order)
```

This algorithm will give you one of the modified topologicaly-sorted paths.