# Is there a name for this sort of graph search?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Let's say you are trying to put together a system consisting of N components.  Some components can't be put in until other components have been put in (can't build the second floor before the first floor) and some components can't be put in unless other components haven't been put in (can't put insulation in the walls after closing up the walls).

Mathematically I'm modelling this by representing each component as one bit in a bitfield.  I start with all zeros, I try to flip one bit at a time, and I have some evaluator function which determines whether or not that flip is an allowed move.  In other words, I start with the empty set and try to add elements of N one by one until they are all in my set.  However, not all such additions are permitted.

According to my math, the graph corresponding to the problem above will have 2^N nodes, with each step S along the building process (so 0 <= S <= N) consisting of N! / (S! * (N-S)!) nodes.  So there are N ways to place the first component, (N^2 - N) / 2 ways to place the second one, and so forth. 
 Each node will have as many parents as it has elements in its subset of N, and the number of parents and children a node has will be equal to the number of elements in N.

O(2^N) is not solvable for anything but very small N, but I wonder if there is a name for this sort of problem so that I could read more about it.

(I apologize in advance for my poor use of technical terminology.)

Answer (score 4):

This seems like it could be solved with a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithm.

> The canonical application of topological sorting is in scheduling a sequence of jobs or tasks based on their dependencies. The jobs are represented by vertices, and there is an edge from x to y if job x must be completed before job y can be started (for example, when washing clothes, the washing machine must finish before we put the clothes in the dryer). Then, a topological sort gives an order in which to perform the jobs

So you would create a graph with a vertex for each of your components, and model the dependencies with edges. For example, if all the components on the first floor must be in place before the second floor can be build, add edges from all the first floor components to all the second floor components (you could possibly simplify this with a single "first floor complete" vertex and make it it depend on all the first floor components, and make all the second floor components depend on it).

To model the fact that the insulation can only be put in if the walls haven't, invert the relationship and model it as an edge from the insulation to the wall, i.e. the wall can only be put on after the insulation has been put in.

Comment: Thank you!  That's helpful reading.  However, inverting the relationship as you describe does not seem straightforward because it may be the case that, for example, you have to build either the inside or the outside side of the wall, but not both, before you put in insulation.

Comment: That's pretty tricky. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642346/how-to-represent-a-dependency-graph-with-alternative-paths). Perhaps you treat the two possibilities (inner -> insulation -> outer, outer -> insulation -> inner) as alternative dependencies?